# Repainting not updating?

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, repaint, mouselistener

As of now, I am trying to work to create a JAVA version of uno that my teacher calls "Singles". Currently, I'm simply trying to get a working deck in which I can remove cards.

My issue currently, though, is that when I remove a card, nothing updates. It doesn't repaint at all. I have no idea why.

Here is the Panel and Frame class.

Panel:

```
package singles;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseListener;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import java.awt.event.MouseMotionListener;
/**
 *
 * @author Xenorosth
 */

public class CardPanel extends JPanel{
    private Card myCard; //To get information for card
    //private static Deck myDeck = new Deck(); //Get a deck!
    public CardPanel(Card myOtherCard){
        this.setSize(100,150);
        this.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100,150));
        myCard = myOtherCard;
        //myCard = myDeck.getMainCard(0);
    }

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
        super.paintComponent(g); 
        g.setColor(Color.black); //Set word drawings to black

        if(myCard.isFlipped()){
            if(myCard.getColor() == "red"){
                this.setBackground(Color.red);
                g.drawString(myCard.getValue(), 30, 30);
            }
            else if(myCard.getColor() == "green"){
                 this.setBackground(Color.green);
                 g.drawString(myCard.getValue(), 30, 30);
            }
            else if(myCard.getColor() == "blue"){
                 this.setBackground(Color.blue);
                 g.drawString(myCard.getValue(), 30, 30);
            }
            else if(myCard.getColor() == "yellow"){
                 this.setBackground(Color.yellow);
                 g.drawString(myCard.getValue(), 30, 30);
            }
            else if(myCard.getColor() == "black"){
            this.setBackground(Color.black);
            g.setColor(Color.white);
            g.drawString(myCard.getValue(), 30, 30);
            g.setColor(Color.black);      
            }
        }
        else{
        this.setBackground(Color.black);
         g.setColor(Color.white);
         g.drawString("Singles", 30, 30);
         g.setColor(Color.black);  

        }


    }

    /**
     * @return the myCard
     */
    public Card getMyCard() {
        return myCard;
    }

    /**
     * @param myCard the myCard to set
     */
    public void setMyC`enter code here`ard(Card myCard) {
        this.myCard = myCard;
    }

}
```

Frame:

```
/*
 * To change this template, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package singles;

import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseListener;
import java.awt.event.MouseMotionListener;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;


/**
 *
 * @author Xenorosth
 */
public class SinglesFrame extends JFrame implements MouseListener, MouseMotionListener{

    Deck myDeck = new Deck();
    CardPanel myTopMain = new CardPanel(myDeck.getMainCard(0)); //Top card of main deck
    CardPanel myTopUsed = new CardPanel(myDeck.getMainCard(1)); //Top card of used deck
    JLabel myLabel1 = new JLabel();


    public SinglesFrame(){
        setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.CENTER));
       // myLabel1.setText(myDeck.getMainDeckLength() + "");
        myTopMain.addMouseListener(this);
        this.add(myTopMain);
        this.add(myTopUsed);
        this.add(myLabel1);

    }

    @Override
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
          myDeck.addUsedCard(myDeck.getMainCard(0));
          myDeck.removeMainCard(0);
          this.repaint();
          System.out.println(myDeck.getMainCard(0).toString());
    }

    @Override
    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
        //throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet.");
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
       // throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet.");
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
    //    throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet.");
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {
       // throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet.");
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {
       // throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet.");
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent e) {
       // throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet.");
    }

}
```

Comment: You're removing the `Card` from the `Deck`, but it has no relevance for the `CardPanel` as it still has a reference to a `Card` that it is painting.  Try changing the `Card` that `CardPanel` is painting and calling `repaint` on it.

Comment: I may not be understanding what you mean. I'm new to Java still, and this is a new topic. I tried changing it from 0 to another constant, but it didn't do a thing. I think I'd need an example, because I'm not getting anywhere trying to change the card. Perhaps I'm not changing it the right way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lets start here...

```
CardPanel myTopMain = new CardPanel(myDeck.getMainCard(0));
CardPanel myTopUsed = new CardPanel(myDeck.getMainCard(1));
```

You create two instances of `CardPanel`.  Each panel is passed a reference to a `Card`

Then in you `mouseClicked` event, you do this...

```
myDeck.addUsedCard(myDeck.getMainCard(0));
myDeck.removeMainCard(0);
this.repaint();
System.out.println(myDeck.getMainCard(0).toString());
```

You've changed the `Deck`, but the reference to `Card` that the two `CardPanel`s are pointing to has not changed.

You need to call (something like) `setMyCard` and either pass in the next card to be shown or `null`.

The next problem you may have is the fact that your `paintComponent` method does not allow for a `null` `Card`

Comment: Either I am not doing this right, or this isn't helping. :/ I've tried using the setMyCard method I made, and literally nothing's changed. Card value changes, but nothing else does.

Comment: Oooooh. I see what you're talking about. Changing the properties, and not the actual card! That worked! Thanks.

Comment: I just noticed that your comparing `String`s wrong.  This `myCard.getColor() == "black"` should done like this `myCard.getColor().equals("black")`